# Spring & Hibernate EJB Events

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa, events, ejb

Is it possible to define a spring-managed EJB3 hibernate listener?

I have this definition in my **persistence.xml**:

```
<properties> 
    <property name="hibernate.ejb.interceptor"
        value="my.class.HibernateAuditInterceptor" /> 
    <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-update"
        value="my.class.HibernateAuditTrailEventListener" /> 
</properties>
```

But I would like to manage `HibernateAuditInterceptor` and `HibernateAuditTrailEventListener` with spring, so I can do some bean injection (ex: session-scoped bean) within these classes. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that those properties are just strings. Even if you define your SessionFactory as a Spring bean, any properties you pass to it through the hibernateProperties setter are just strings:

```
<bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource"ref="myDataSource"/>
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>whatever.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.ejb.interceptor= my.class.HibernateAuditInterceptor
        </value>
        <value>
            hibernate.ejb.event.post-update=my.class.HibernateAuditTrailEventListener
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

So I don't think you can do that.

Comment: Hibernate's SessionFactory accepts a listener when opening sessions. I'm sure this can be done with spring managing both the session factory and the listener; my problem is with JPA.

Answer (score 3):

http://blog.krecan.net/2009/01/24/spring-managed-hibernate-interceptor-in-jpa/