# What kinds of Hibernate events exist?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have this legacy application which defines a custom listener for `hibernate.ejb.event.flush` and I wondered if there are any other events available? So I searched the web and eventually found [`hibernate.ejb.event.post-update`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/258344/3890673) - but I didn't find an official documentation with a complete list... well, there is [this doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/ejb/event/package-summary.html), but it doesn't state the actual String (such as "post-update").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/configuration.html#d0e865) the full list of event listeners supported by the EntityManager is the following:

- flush
- auto-flush
- delete
- flush-entity
- merge
- create
- create-onflush
- save
- save-update
- pre-insert
- pre-insert
- pre-delete
- pre-load
- post-delete
- post-insert
- post-load
- post-update

So in order to set any of them you should replace in `hibernate.ejb.event.<event_name>`  with the proper event.